# Criar as próprias tags afeta em alguma coisa?

Tags: html, css

Eu estou criando um sistema de criação de páginas Web para pessoas que não tem experiência em programação, mas a organização da página é feita através de tags.

Por exemplo:

```html
<conteudo>
    <artigo class="flex quebra">
        <postagem class="completo">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam corrupti atque natus.</p>
        </postagem>
        <postagem class="metade">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam corrupti atque natus.</p>
        </postagem>
    </artigo>
    <lado>
        <widget>
            <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
            <conteudo>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam neque itaque dolor sunt, illo!
            </conteudo>
        </widget>
    </lado>
</conteudo>
```

Eu sei que devia ter uma div para cada item, mas como é destinado para pessoas que não tem nenhuma experiência, ficaria mais fácil assim. Isso futuramente afetaria **muito** o posicionamento das páginas nos mecanismos de busca?

Comment: Você não pode identificar o elemento pela class ao invés da tag? Transformando `<artigo class="flex quebra">` para `<div class="tagArtigo flex quebra">` por exemplo.

Comment: A questão é: o quão fazer da forma com que fiz afetaria negativamente a página em mecanismos de busca?

Comment: Se é pra fazer isso, muito melhor simplificar a sintaxe toda, e não só mudar o nome das tags. A intenção é boa, a solução é sofrida. Lembrando ainda que se usar tags próprias, não é mais HTML, passa a ser no máximo um XML, que só vai funcionar graças à flexibilidade dos navegadores.

Comment: Entendo que não é a melhor solução, mas, por agora, é necessário ser assim. A questão principal é sobre os robôs de busca. Por favor, quem souber responder a pergunta, agradeço.

Comment: Update da especificação: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem vários fatores que interferem na relevância da sua página em relação as outras.

A começar pelo tipo de documento "Doctype" , que é a primeira tag a ser analisada em documentos de marcação de texto.

Como citado pelo @bacco, seu documento, da forma que está, terá relevância negativa, pois nem ao menos um tipo de documento foi declarado.

Se declarar o doctype como sendo html, também não vai ajudar, pois o html possui seu próprio padrão de tags.

Sendo assim, vc pode usar as tags que está usando, no entanto ao pensar em relevância nos buscadores, deve estruturar seu documento em conformidade com as padrões adotados a cada tipo e variação de "doctype".