# Como utilizar a tag style em parte de um texto?

Tags: html, css

Quero fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

`<p style="color:red;">Esse texto é vermelho e <style="color:blue;">esse texto é azul</style> mas esse outro continua vermelho</p>`

Creio que tenham entendido. Eu quero pegar um trecho do texto e alterar apenas a cor de algumas palavras, mas o resto continua igual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a tag `<span></span>`

```
<p style="color:red;">Esse texto é vermelho e <span style="color:blue;">esse texto é azul</span> mas esse outro continua vermelho</p>
```

a tag `<style></style>` é para inserir CSS e não um tag de marcação

```html
<p style="color:red;">Esse texto é vermelho e <span style="color:blue;">esse texto é azul</span> mas esse outro continua vermelho</p>
```

Comment: A tag `mark`não serve para alterar a cor de um texto. A função da tag é destacar um trecho do texto como se fosse um marcador de texto.

Comment: sim, serve como um marca texto. Por isso editei e citei a tag span tbm e coloquei o background: none algumas versões anteriores de Chrome/Firefox não tinha background default e ficava sem nada. mas editei e coloquei a tag span

Comment: É porque é uma tag HTML5 que não funciona em algumas versões antigas de navegadores.

Comment: @sam, com a tag `<tiosam></tiosam>` funciona, veja minha resposta

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo `<vovô></vovô>` tb funciona em navegadores da década de 90.

Comment: @sam editei a resposta

Answer (score 2):

**Você pode usar tag personalizada.**

```html
<p style="color:red;">Esse texto é vermelho e <tiosam style="color:blue;">esse texto é azul</tiosam> mas esse outro continua vermelho</p>
```

Se o seu PC é da decada de 90 use a tag `vovô`

```html
<p style="color:red;">Esse texto é vermelho e <vovô style="color:blue;">esse texto é azul</vovô> mas esse outro continua vermelho</p>
```

> Só lembrando que, além deste comentário ter sido IMPORTADO, vale lembrar também que elementos custom ainda estão em adoção, e para garantir que sejam válidos é o caso de acompanhar a especificação. Em princípio, funcionam baseado na tolerância dos navegadores. Mais detalhes: [**Elementos personalizados**](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/)

[Living Standard — Last Updated 19 September 2018 - 4.13 Custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements)

Comment: Será que tem a ver com semântica? rs

Comment: @sam, a tags vovô e tiosam fazem chongas mas aceitam style

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134816/criar-as-pr%c3%b3prias-tags-afeta-em-alguma-coisa#comment279355_134816

Comment: Só lembrando que elementos custom ainda estão em adoção, e para garantir que sejam válidos é o caso de acompanhar a especificação. Em princípio, funcionam baseado na tolerância dos navegadores. Mais detalhes: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/